# How can I get round social media buttons with that code snippet?

Tags: html, css

I have the following code to create social media buttons. I use them in my wordpress blog in a sidebar.

```css
@import url("//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.1.0/css/font-awesome.min.css");

/* General rule */

.dist {
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.button-big {
  font-size: 2em;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0.2em 0em 0.2em 0em;
  display: inline-block;
}
/* Facebook class and animation */

.facebook {
  color: #3B5998;
  border: 1px solid #3B5998;
}
.facebook:hover {
  animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: facebookAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes facebookAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    border: 1px solid #3B5998;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* YouTube class and animation */

.youtube {
  color: #bb0000;
  border: 1px solid #bb0000;
}
.youtube:hover {
  animation: ytAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: ytAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@keyframes ytAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@-webkit-keyframes ytAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #bb0000;
    border: 1px solid #bb0000;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* Instagram class and animation */

.instagram {
  color: #125688;
  border: 1px solid #125688;
}
.instagram:hover {
  animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
  -webkit-animation: instaAnim 0.4s normal forwards linear;
}
@-webkit-keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
@keyframes instaAnim {
  50% {
    background-color: #125688;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: #125688;
    border: 1px solid #125688;
    color: #fff;
  }
}
/* link styles */

.facebook a {
  color: #3B5998;
}
.youtube a {
  color: #bb0000;
}
.instagram a {
  color: #125688;
}
.facebook a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.youtube a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
.instagram a:hover {
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
  <a href="#">
<div class="facebook button-big">
<i class="fa fa-facebook"></i>
</div></a>
<a href="#"><div class="youtube button-big dist">
 <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i>
</div></a>

<a href="#"><div class="instagram button-big dist">
 <i class="fa fa-instagram"></i>
</div></a>
```

Does anyone know how to get them round? I think that'd look much better! I tried different things but nothing worked for me! It would be great if someone could help me!

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `border-radius: 50%;` of this css class `button-big`

Answer (score 0):

I got it, `border-radius: 50%;` was the solution.
But thank you!

Comment: Well Bugaloo did tell you that, so you may wanna credit the guy